# how to get last value of any attribute in postgresql pivot table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

```
  id     u_id   attr_key   attr_value   process_id     insert_time
------|-------|----------|------------|--------------|--------------
   1      1      name          john          1              1       
   2      1      family        smith         1              2
   3      2       job          clerk         2              3
   4      1       name         sarah         3              4
.............
```

I have to find two things:

1. I have to create a view by tablefunc(crosstab) to fetch a group of data for any of u_id  ..so it's simple
2. I have  to find (realtime) last value of any key of any u_id (like Hbase database) so I don't have any good solution

this is what i need

```
  id     u_id   attr_key   attr_value
------|-------|----------|------------
   4      1       name         sarah 
   2      1      family        smith
```

Any idea or function?
(its possible to add a column in my data model )

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. And you should only ask one question per question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient solution to [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems in Postgres is to use [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

The following will retrieve that for a single `u_id`

```
select distinct on (attr_key) id, u_id, attr_key, attr_value
from the_table
where u_id = 1
order by attr_key, insert_time desc;
```

An index on `(u_id, attr_key, insert_time)` should help for performance

Comment: thanks horse , but do you  think, its a good solution for over 50,000,000 row

Comment: It's pretty efficient and should perform well if properly indexed - especially if you query for a single `u_id` (assuming you do not mean 50 million rows **per user**). You need to test for yourself, on your data and your hardware though.